# Parsing Error: Unexpected token, expect ",": Stateless functional Component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint

I'm using a stateless functional component to draw a graph, the data for the graph will be passed down via props inside of my parent component.

I'm not sure if my error is due to syntax or my linter.

The error is on line 45, where I am trying to use props inside of a function that draws my chart

```
const DoughutChart = (props) => {
  const getOptions = () => ({
    tooltip: {
      trigger: 'item',
      formatter: '{a} <br/>{b} : {c} ({d}%)',
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: 'Proportion of all learning in each capability area',
        type: 'pie',
        radius: ['55%', '80%'],
        avoidLabelOverlap: true,
        label: {
          normal: {
            show: true,
            position: 'outside',
          },
          emphasis: {
            show: true,
            textStyle: {
              fontWeight: 'bold',
            },
          },
        },
        labelLine: {
          normal: {
            lineStyle: {
              color: 'rgba(218, 223, 225, 1)',
            },
            smooth: 0.2,
            length: 15,
            length2: 25,
          },
        },
        itemStyle: {
          emphasis: {
            shadowBlur: 10,
            shadowOffsetX: 0,
            shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
          },
        },
        data: {props.data}, // Parsing Error: Unexpected token, expected ","
      },
    ],
  })
  return <ReactEcharts option={getOptions} style={{ height: 350, width: 530 }} />
}
export default DoughutChart
```

.eslintrc

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 6,
      "sourceType": "module",
      "ecmaFeatures": {
          "jsx": true,
          "modules": true,
          "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
      }
  },
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "airbnb",
    "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended",
    "prettier",
    "prettier/react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "jsx-a11y",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "semi": 0,
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"] }],
    "no-param-reassign": ["error", { "props": false }],
    "prettier/prettier": [
      "error", {
        "semi": false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: `{props.data}` is invalid syntax. If you're trying to pass along the data object, remove the curly braces.

Comment: Ah, so simple. Thank you!